# How to replace {{var}} in an HTML document to a variable using Python 3

Tags: python, html

How can I put variables from dict into an HTML document?

Like in replace {{variable}} with 1 in the HTML document with Python.

Python code:

```py
def convert_html_to_python(variables={}, code=""):
    ## Stuff with code variable
some_code = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    {{var}}
</body>
</html>
"""
convert_html_to_python({"var":"1"}, some_code)
```

Then the Python script converts HTML document to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    1
</body>
</html>
```

I want it to be like [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) templates. I do not want to use Django or Flask.

Comment: I don’t know exactly what you need to do, vue I think flask and django come with a template engine for html.

Comment: i dont want to use a framework.

Comment: @InsaneMiner you can use jinja2 alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method on the string.

```
def convert_html_to_python(variables={}, code=""):
    for variable in variables:
        code = code.replace("{{"+str(variable)+"}}", variables[variable])
    return code

some_code = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>My First Heading</h1>
    <p>My first paragraph.</p>
    {{var}}
</body>
</html>
"""
print(convert_html_to_python({"var":"1"}, some_code))
```

Answer (score 1):

Flask and Django comes with a solution for this.
You can try reading an HTML file like a string and change it.

For example:

#### HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Function to add data:

```
def add_data(data, html_code):
    write_index = html_code.find('</body>') - 1
    html_code = html_code[:write_index] + '\n<h1>' + data + '</h1>\n' + html_code[write_index + 1:]
    print(html_code)
```

#### HTML now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<h1>~~data we insert in~~</h1>
</body>
</html>
```